# Delete matched item for String in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to `vba` programming and currently working on following:

1. record attributes name for the data and record it to `AttributeName()`
2. request user to select target / dependent variable
3. delete the target attributes from `AttributeName()`

I have problems to proceed step 3 (I used `Filter()` and `.Delete`)

```
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim nrow As Long
Dim ncol As Long

Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select

Set DataRange = Selection
nrow = DataRange.Rows.Count
ncol = DataRange.Columns.Count

Dim AttributeName() As String
For i = 1 to ncol
        ReDim Preserve AttributeName(i)
    AttributeName(i) = Sheets("data").Cells(1,i).Value
Next i


Dim TargetRange as Range
    Dim Target as String
Set TargetRange = Application.InputBox("Please highlight the cell for TARGET", Type:=8)
Target = TargetRange.Value
```

My idea is : 
 `If AttributeName(i) = Target Then ...`

Thanks for your gentle help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you're going to remove elements** from `AttributeName`, consider about using **Collection** ([link 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/gg251465%28v=office.15%29.aspx) and [link 2](http://www.functionx.com/vbaexcel/objects/Lesson6.htm)) instead Array:

```
Dim AttributeName As New Collection
For i = 1 To ncol
    AttributeName.Add Sheets("data").Cells(1, i).Value
Next i

Dim TargetRange As Range
Dim Target As String
Set TargetRange = Application.InputBox("Please highlight the cell for TARGET", Type:=8)
Target = TargetRange.Value

With AttributeName
    For i = .Count To 1 Step -1
        If .Item(i) = Target Then .Remove (i)
    Next
End With
```

---

**Also one important thing**, what would be if user press "Cancel" in InputBox? You should handle this as well.

Change

```
Set TargetRange = Application.InputBox("Please highlight the cell for TARGET", Type:=8)
```

to

```
On Error Resume Next
Set TargetRange = Application.InputBox("Please highlight the cell for TARGET", Type:=8)
On Error Goto 0

If TargetRange Is Nothing Then
   MsgBox "User has pressed cancel"
   Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Hi Simoco! Thanks so much! <br/>
It works perfect! Collection!